# Using CSS nth-child to select irregular pattern in sequence

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I need to select the following in sequence with CSS3 `nth-child` if possible but can't figure out how to...

70% Width

```
1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 17, 20
```

(+3+1r)

30% Width

```
2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19
```

(+1+3r)

I can only see a way of selecting the same increment in sequence (i.e 1, 5, 9, 13, 17) so wondered if anyone could advise of a few single rules to select as per the above or whether I would require some overlapping rules that override as necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `nth-child(4n+0)` and `nth-child(4n+1)` in combination should select the required elements.

1, 4, 5, 8, 9... would be selected by the above combination while the other sequence is the remaining items. So set the 30% width as default and over-ride to 70% on the selected `nth-child` combinations.

```css
div{
    background: green;
}
div:nth-child(4n+0),
div:nth-child(4n+1){
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
<div>20</div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, what a life saver! Does exactly what I was after. Thanks :)

Comment: @zigojacko to complete harry's answer, you can use `:nth-child(4n-2)` and `:nth-child(4n-1)` for the other situation : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/j90e4sex/